# Regex - mod_rewrite - Match string after characters and run as get vars

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm looking to find and capture the url by "/-" and run the resulting find as a single get var on the preceding page:

```
http://domain.com/about-us/contact/-foo/-bar
```

would run as:

```
http://domain.com/about-us/contact/?get=/-foo/-bar
```

I'm able to find the match with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/-.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1 [L]
```

But have been unsuccessful returning the proper get var. This yields:

```
http://domain.com/?get=about-us/contact/-foo/-bar
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue to the redirect vs. rewrite I was having. Basically I need to make sure and put the file in `index.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/-.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(\/-.*)$ $1/index.php?get=$2 [L]
```

Thanks, Jason for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're matching the whole URL in the `RewriteRule`, instead break it up into the base and the rest since you already predetermined the URL format with `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/-.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(\/-.*)$ $1?get=$2 [L]
```

**Note:** There are other ways to do this without `RewriteRule`. However, this is most like your current code.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. This is working perfectly, though I can't keep it from acting as a redirect as opposed to a mask? Is that because we're matching everything in the $1 var (including the http://) and this is telling it to behave as a redirect? I'll keep digging. Thanks!

Comment: Define *redirect*, it should not be redirecting in the traditional sense (i.e. 301/302)

Comment: So the url is changing from 'domain.com/about-us/-foo' to 'domain.com/about-us/?get=/-foo' I'm hoping to get it to be masked so that the url doesn't change, but I have the get var available to my scripts.

Comment: Is it changing in the browser? Of course it's changing in the code, you're rewriting it.

Comment: Yes, it's changing in the browser.

Comment: So I haven't been able to figure this out yet. Here's my .htaccess: `Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/-.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(\/-.*)$ $1?get=$2 [L]` and the live result: [http://www.staticoak.com/about-us/check/-foo/-bar](http://www.staticoak.com/about-us/check/-foo/-bar)